# Gammu SMS gateway service shows "Error 27"

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, gammu

This is my first experience using Gammu as SMS gateway, and I have a problem with the setup.

This is my system:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Gammu 1.33.0 Windows x64
- XAMPP 1.8.1
- Database connection to MySQL using ODBC
- GSM modem used: Wavecom Fastrack M1306B

And here is my smsdrc:

```
[gammu]
port = com6:
connection = at115200

[smsd]
Service = sql
Driver = odbc
SQL = mysql
host = localmysql
DeliveryReport = sms
logfile = smsdlog
debuglevel = 1
PIN = 1234
commtimeout = 1
sendtimeout = 10
User = root
Password = 
# host = localhost
PC = localhost
Database = smsd
```

And here is my gammudrc :

```
port = com6:
connection = at115200
```

What I've did:

- Extract the directory of `gammu/bin` into `xampp/htdocs/gammu`
- Created smsrdc & gammurc files with the configs above
- Set the compatibility of gammu-smsd.exe to Run As Administrator
- phpmyadmin > Create new db (smsd) > imported the sql from `gammu\share\doc\gammu\examples\sql\mysql.sql`
- My ODBC settings : 
  [image: ODBC]
  <sub>(source: [kaskus.com](http://cdn.kaskus.com/images/2014/01/08/270124_20140108080555.png))</sub>

(I've tested and it's connected)
 - I've added the gammu-smsd into windows serices
 - test identify by running `gammu --identify`
 - test sending sms manually from console
 - test `gammu-smsd -c smsdrc`, and i had no error at all.

The problem is I couldn't run the gammu-smsd as a service, whether it's manually from the cmd nor started it from the services.

1. If I started the gammu-smsd from cmd ( `gammu-smsd -c smsdrc -s` ), the gammu-smsd showed up in the task manager, but disappeared in less than 1 sec.
2. Whenever I tried to manually start the gammu-smsd service from the Windows Services, it always shows me this kind of error:

(broken image: `http://cdn.kaskus.com/images/2014/01/08/270124_20140108085812.png`)

I've done some searchs, and what I've found is all about wrong connection into DB, port, or about Run As Administrator. But I'm quite sure it's not from config.

How can I solve this issue, so that I can run the gammu-smsd services properly?
Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running not as a service :
gammu-smsd -c smsdrc

in my case that do the job.